# How do I determine if a color is warm or cool using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, colors, cielab

I'm trying to create two functions `isCool(color)` and `isWarm(color)`that return boolean values when passed an RGB color as an argument. These functions should be able to tell if a color is warm or cool based on the channel values of the color.

```
import { 

   add, 

   clamp, 

   gt, 

   inRange, 

   lt, 

   lte, 

   stubFalse, 

   stubTrue, 

 } from "lodash-es"; 

 import { converter } from "culori"; 

 import { getTemp } from "../core-utils/rgb2temperature.ts"; 

 import type { baseColor } from "../paramTypes.ts"; 

 import { format } from "../core-utils/format.ts"; 

  

 const isCool = (color: baseColor) => { 

   // Make sure the color is parseable by converter() 

   const xyz = converter("xyz65")(format(color)); 

   console.log(xyz); 

   // I want to clip colors within the 

   // Double conversion from XYZ to Lab. Why though ??? 

   color = converter("lab65")(color); 

   console.log(color); 

  

   // i need to take account of the different channel values for certain color ranges 

   let r, g, b, y; 

  

   // Coords for red,green,yellow,blue 

   y = b = { start: 0, end: clamp(color["b"], 100, 1) }; 

   b = { start: 0, end: clamp(color["b"], -100, 0) }; 

   g = { start: 0, end: clamp(color["a"], -100, 0) }; 

   r = { start: 0, end: clamp(color["a"], 100, 1) }; 

   // Check the ranges of the *a and *b component 

   return inRange(color["a"], g["start"], g["end"]) && 

     inRange(color["b"], b["start"], b["end"]) 

     ? stubTrue() 

     : stubFalse(); 

 }; 

  

 export { isCool };
```

In the above code sample I was trying to do an AND check that returns true if the color's `a`  and `b` channel are in the defined ranges then it returns true else false. However when I pass in "blue" (which is a cool color) to `isCool()` its returning false

```
import { 
   add, 
   clamp, 
   gt, 
   inRange, 
   lt, 
   lte, 
   stubFalse, 
   stubTrue, 
 } from "lodash-es"; 
 import { converter } from "culori"; 
 import { getTemp } from "../core-utils/rgb2temperature.ts"; 
 import type { baseColor } from "../paramTypes.ts"; 
 import { format } from "../core-utils/format.ts"; 
  
 const isCool = (color: baseColor) => { 
   const { r, g, b } = color; 
   // Make sure the color is parseable by converter() 
  
   // Double conversion from XYZ to Lab. Why though ??? 
   color = converter("lab65")(format(color)); 
  
   // Capture the cool and warm ranges (starts and ends) 
   const cool = { start: -100, end: -20 }; 
   const warm = { start: 40, end: 100 }; 
  
   const isACool = 
     inRange(g, cool["start"], cool["end"]) && 
     inRange(b, cool["start"], cool["end"]); 
   const isAWarm = 
     inRange(g, warm["start"], warm["end"]) && 
     inRange(b, warm["start"], warm["end"]); 
  
   // i need to take account of the different channel values for certain color ranges 
   const isCoolColor = isACool && gt(color["a"], 0); 
   const isWarmColor = isAWarm && gt(color["a"], 0); 
   return isCoolColor || isWarmColor; 
 }; 
  
 export { isCool };
```

I changed the code to the above but its still returning false.